# How To Add Shipping Address During CheckOut Process in ATG

Tags: java, atg

I'm Fresher and I'm new in ATG and right now working on checkout module. Here I'm trying to take shipping information of user so it is fetching in the shipping information JSP but when I'm trying to submit that JSP, it's not going to either successURL or the errorURL, it remains on the current JSP.

I'm not doing any customizations I'm just using all Out Of Box Components and my code is almost the same as Out Of Box Code and it is not giving any error also.

Comment: Show some code, please.

Comment: Generally the `errorURL` is the current page so there is likely to be a `formexception`. Try turning on `loggingDebug` for the `formhandler` and then provide the output of the log as an edit to your question.

Comment: Hi @radimpe 
I'm not doing any customizations so how can I turn on logging debug.

Comment: In the property file for the `FormHandler` add the following line `loggingDebug=true`.